# Execute two UIView at the same time (Not sequentially)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, animation, uiview, block

I was surfing the net but I could not have an answer for the problem that I have. 
I `m developing an iPhone app. 
Here the problem: I have tree UIView A, B and C.
A and B are into C.
When C have a result to show, I want to execute A and B at the same time. A and B are a counter animation each one takes 5 sec. to finish. but I can not find a way to show counter animation of A and B at the same time. Always B is executed when A animation has finished.
I tried  with blocks ( dispatch_queue_t)but I have the same result.
Is possible do what I trying to do?

Edited:
The problem in the [code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1348024/Counters.zip) is that the counters (A and B) are not executed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startAnimation];
}

-(void)startAnimation {

   //Creating views
   UIView *v1 = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)];
   v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   [self.view addSubview:v1];

   UIView *v2 = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 240, 40, 40)];
   v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.view addSubview:v2];

    //Animating views
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     v1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 240, 40, 40);
                 }];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     v2.frame = CGRectMake(140, 10, 40, 40);
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your answer !! I prove your code it is working !
But I cant execute my A and B UIview at the same time. I will edit my question and put my code. If you want you will see that the counters are not being executed at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately your code didn't run on my computer. But, I was thinking if you could put your code in only one animation statement like this: '[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         v1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 240, 40, 40);
                         v2.frame = CGRectMake(140, 10, 40, 40);

                     }];'. What do you think ?

Comment: I did that!! … I put the counters A and B in the same animation code and it didn`t work.
May be because A and B has its own animation... I mind A and B are the famous Apple FlipCounters here the link to the GIT original project [link](https://github.com/reklis/flipcounter)
I used two instances of FlipConuterView.h and FlipConuterView.m of that project in a UIView.